# Serial device only returns position data every other time

Tags: python, serial-port, nvidia-jetson

I have python code for reading the current position data from a serial pan-tilt-zoom (PTZ) device in response to a command I send it. This code works fine on a Raspberry Pi, but on a Jetson Orin Nano, it gives empty results on every other write + read command sequence. To work around this, I am sending the "get position" command again after each read.

Is there a better solution to ensure reliable reading from this device?

```
import serial
import time

COM_PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
BAUD_RATE = 9600
CMD_GET_POS = b'Rllllllllll'

def get_position():
    ser = serial.Serial(COM_PORT, BAUD_RATE, timeout=1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write(CMD_GET_POS)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    read_val = ser.readline()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # The workaround required for next read to work on Jetson Orin Nano for some reason.
    ser.write(CMD_GET_POS)

    current_pos = {'h': 0, 'v': 0}
    if isinstance(read_val, bytes):
        current_pos_data = read_val.decode()
        if current_pos_data:
            current_h = int(current_pos_data[1:4])
            current_v = int(current_pos_data[4:7])
            current_pos = {'h': current_h, 'v': current_v}

    return current_pos 

def test_get_position():
    for i in range(3):
        print(f"get_position {i} {get_position()}")
        time.sleep(0.5)

test_get_position()
```

Comment: (1) Opening/initializing the serial connection every time you perform a write+read operation is inefficient. (2) The delays around the write & read are unnecessary. The sleep *after* the read is nonsensical; why would you *add* latency before the processing? "*This code works fine ..., but on a Jetson Orin Nano, it only works every other ...*" -- So what actually does happen when it "*doesn't work*"?

Comment: @sawdust, It gives empty results on every other write + read command sequence. Regarding your first note, does my code open/initialize a connection when a previous one wasn't closed?

Comment: "*does my code open/initialize a connection when a previous one wasn't closed?*" -- I'm not a Python expert, but I think you have no basis to assume that `serial.Serial()` could be a NOP. For instance the documentation for [serial.Serial.port](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.port) says "When the port is already open, it will be closed and reopened with the new setting." Since your program is not behaving exactly like you expect, you need to start suspecting every assumption that you have made, and test those assumptions to see if they are actually true